# NTILE Function and Using Inner Join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, percentile

I am supposed to use the given Database(Its pretty huge so I used codeshare) to list last names and customer numbers of top 5% of customers for each branch. To find the top 5% of customers, I decided to use the NTILE Function, (100/5 = 20, hence NTILE 20). The columns are pulled from two separate tables so I used Inner joins. For the life of me, I honesly cannot figure out where I am going wrong. I keep getting "missing expression" errors but Do not know what exactly I am missing. Here is the Database

Database: https://codeshare.io/5XKKBj
ERD: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzum6VJXi9lUX1d2ZkhudTE3QXc/view?usp=sharing

Here is my SQL Query so far.

```
SELECT
  Ntile(20) over
    (partition by Employee.Branch_no
     order by sum(ORDERS.SUBTOTAL) desc
    ) As Top_5,
  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO,
  CUSTOMER.LNAME
FROM
  CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN ORDERS
  ON
  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NO
GROUP BY
  ORDERS.SUBTOTAL,
  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO,
  CUSTOMER.LNAME;
```

Comment: (1) you're missing the `Employee` table; (2) the `GROUP BY` must include all non-aggregate expressions in the `SELECT` clause (i.e. you are aggregating `ORDERS.SUBTOTAL` so you can't include that in the `GROUP BY`); (3) consider using a subquery to collate the source data before applying the `NTILE`.

Comment: Wouldn't using Employee.Branch_no equate to actually having a table in there? The only thing I can think of is using another inner join but seems like a waste. Can you please explain the subquery?

Comment: You can't refer to a table that is not joined. That's what joins are for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join `Employee` and the `GROUP BY` must include all non-aggregated expressions. You can use a subquery to generate the subtotals and get the `NTILE` in the outer query, e.g.:

```
SELECT
  Ntile(20) over
    (partition by BRANCH_NO
     order by sum_subtotal desc
    ) As Top_5,
  CUSTOMER_NO,
  LNAME
FROM (
  SELECT
    EMPLOYEE.BRANCH_NO,
    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO,
    CUSTOMER.LNAME,
    sum(ORDERS.SUBTOTAL) as sum_subtotal
  FROM CUSTOMER
  JOIN ORDERS
    ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NO
  JOIN EMPLOYEE
    ON ORDERS.EMPLOYEE_NO = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NO
  GROUP BY
    EMPLOYEE.BRANCH_NO,
    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO,
    CUSTOMER.LNAME
  );
```

*Note: you might want to include `BRANCH_NO` in the select list as well, otherwise the output will look confusing with duplicate customers (if a customer has ordered from employees in multiple branches).*

Now, if you want to filter the above query to just get the top 5%, you can put the whole thing in another subquery and add a predicate on the `Top_5` column, e.g.:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NO, LNAME
FROM (... the query above...)
WHERE Top_5 = 1;
```